Proxy object tries to write unset values to database
I think my entity manager is tracking changes I didn't make. It is trying to write unset values in a proxy back to the database.
Symfony 6.4.5, php 8.2.17, ORM 2.19.3, enable_lazy_ghost_objects: true
I have an EntityA that has EAGER loaded ManyToOne relation to EntityB. EntityB also has EAGER loaded ManyToOne relation to EntityC.
I have a simple controller to edit EntityA. It loads EntityA in the action arg, e.g. public function edit(EntityA $a): Response {}.
In the controller I make a few changes to $a and then flush the entity manager. On flush I get the error

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column ‘first_name’ cannot be null

first_name is a property of both EntityB and EntityC. The problem is that the related entities already have non-null values. It appears that the proxy is not loading the relations and then on flush, attempting to write the non-loaded values back on the entity. What am I doing wrong?
using xdebug, I can see that EntityB is fully hydrated, but EntityC is only a proxy object with unset values.
if I add $foo = $a->getB()->getC(); to the code, the proxy is not resolved, it remains a proxy
Both EntityA and EntityB extend the same abstract class Person which is annotated as #[MappedSuperClass]

UPDATE: setting enable_lazy_ghost_objects:false works and all the errors disappear. So the problem has something to do with that, but I guess I need to figure out a way to fix the problem without setting that to false

Proxies are only resolved, when they need to be resolved (when a "missing" field is accessed, i.e. a non-id field). However, the ORM should also not try to update the database from the missing values on them but instead be aware that they're proxy objects. If the ORM tries to do this, that sounds like a bug to me.

@Jakumi thank you for responding. I have created a reproducer and submitted a bug report

tbh, this is most likely a doctrine/orm bug, not a symfony bug (symfony uses doctrine as the default orm)
